# Asp.Net MVC HttpException The layout page ""/(X(1) could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, layout, view

From times to times i am getting the following exception logged:

```
HttpException: The layout page ""/(X(1))/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml"" could not be found at the following path: ""/(X(1))/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml"".
Stack:    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Have no X(1) in my system, no idea where it is coming from and why it occurs just from time to time. Is the framework putting it there? 
Running out of ideas here.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What do you have in your view?

Comment: Just javascript and callings to partial views and section render     @{Html.RenderPartial("_HeaderBar");} 

    @RenderSection("pageHeaders", true)

Comment: The weird thing is that it just happens from time to time, i cant reproduce the problem on my system but it is happening live for some reason.

Comment: Until you give more information, it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: i have no idea where it is coming from. Happens from time to time and in different places. So in fact i am really wondering if someone has ever seen that X(1) that is being added there for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with ASP.Net Cookieles feature, that is where the X(1) comes from.
Give a look to the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx
Thanks